# Why DETR need to set a empty class?

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

Why DETR need to set a empty class?
It has set a "Background" class, which means non-object, why?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

By default DETR always predict 100 bounding boxes. Empty class is used as a condition to filter out meaningless bounding boxes.

**Full explanation**

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr/blob/8a144f83a287f4d3fece4acdf073f387c5af387d/models/detr.py#L65-L69), the transformer decoder transforms each query from `self.query_embed.weight` into the output `hs`:

```py
hs = self.transformer(self.input_proj(src), mask, self.query_embed.weight, pos[-1])[0]
```

Then a linear layer `self.class_embed` maps `hs` into the object class `outputs_class`. Another linear layer `self.bbox_embed` maps the same `hs` into bounding box `outputs_coord`:

```
outputs_class = self.class_embed(hs)
outputs_coord = self.bbox_embed(hs).sigmoid()
out = {'pred_logits': outputs_class[-1], 'pred_boxes': outputs_coord[-1]}
```

The number of bounding boxes is set to `num_queries` (by default [100](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr/blob/eb9f7e03ed8e2ed2cd55528989fe7df890bc3fc0/hubconf.py#L20)).

```py
detr = DETR(backbone_with_pos_enc, transformer, num_classes=num_classes, num_queries=100)
```

As you can see now, without the empty class, DETR will always predict 100 bounding boxes (DETR will always try to bound this and that 100 times), even though when there is only one object in the image.

Now, let us consider the example below. There are only two meaningful objects (two birds). But DETR still predicts 100 bounding boxes. Thankfully 98 of the boxes corresponding to "empty class" are discarded (the green box and the blue box below, plus the remaining 96 boxes not shown in the pic below). Only the red box and yellow box having the output class of "bird" are meaningful and hence considered as the prediction.

[image]

That is how DETR makes dynamic object prediction. It can predict any number of objects less than or equal to `num_queries`, but not more than this. If you want DETR to predict more than 100 objects, say 500. Then you can set `num_queries` to 500 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cross-attention at the first decoder layer will update the class embeddings of the queries based on the learned positional embeddings.

The cross-attention weights used in DETR are computed as:

```
(query + query_pos) @ (key + key_pos)^T
```

here `query` is the class embeddings of queries, at the first layer they were meaningless (initialized as all zeros), but the `query_pos` are learned representing the rough detection region of the queries. After the first layer, the class embeddings are updated mainly based on the similarity between `query_pos` and `key_pos`. Therefore, the class embeddings after the first layer are focusing mainly on the features around the position of the queries.